# Unable to deploy Synapse code with override parameters with GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a YAML script with which I'm trying to deploy synapse code into production environment workspace with GitHub actions. I'm successfully deploying code into production workspace without any issues, but when I'm trying to deploy with override parameters, values are not getting updated after deployment into workspace.
Please find the below script for your reference. I have removed sensitive values from the below script.

```
name: workspace deployment
on:
  push:
    branches: [ workspace_publish ]
jobs:
  release:
    # You also can use the self-hosted runners.
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      # Checks out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it.
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: azure/synapse-workspace-deployment@release-1.0
        with:
          TargetWorkspaceName: 'synapseprod196'
          TemplateFile: ./synapsedev196/TemplateForWorkspace.json
          ParametersFile: ./synapsedev196/TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json
          OverrideArmParameters: |
              {
                "workspaceName": "synapseprod196",
                "synapsedev196-WorkspaceDefaultSqlServer_connectionString" : "" 
                "AzureDataLakeStorage1_accountKey": "",
                "synapsedev196-WorkspaceDefaultStorage_properties_typeProperties_url": "https://adlstr16.dfs.core.windows.net",
                "AzureDataLakeStorage1_properties_typeProperties_url": "https://adlstr16.dfs.core.windows.net/",
              }
           environment: 'Azure Public'
           CLIENTID : ''
           CLIENTSECRET : ''
           resourceGroup: 'SynDev'
           subscriptionId: ''
           tenantId: ''
           DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: 'true'
           managedIdentity: 'False'
```

Please let me know how we can deploy code with override parameters step into workspace.

I tried changing the format of the override parameters but still it didn't succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the action are you using?. In the documentation it explains that in order to override the parameters you need to create a file in the root folder of the branch, with the parameters and the new values in a key:value format. Have you tried this approach?

[image: Overriding parameters]

Cheers!